# how to store an object model into an array in the session and keep the relations updated with database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to store an array of model objects ( carts ) in the session but the problem is when I print out these carts their relationships are not updated with the database

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to post code. paste the code in a code block in the question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I personally only save the id's in the session -> smaller session size and keeps the models up to date with the db.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of approaching this problem.

**1 - store only the ID**
If you store only the id of the data in the session, when you get the model back from the ID, Eloquent fetches all the relation properly.

**2 - Serialize the model in the session**
Laravel and Eloquent provides a way to serialize objects and particularly models : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization
A serialized model is a JSON string that you can store in session.

But you need to rehydrate the model with JSON data when you get it back from the session so in the end it's not easier than storing the id and reloading the model from the DB.

**PS:**
You can also take a look at **model caching** if you need to store instance of a model that is rarely updated to save database access:
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching